# How to extract a bytes data in string type in python?

Tags: python

```
str1 = "b'E\\x00\\x05\\xad\\\\\\xd9\\x00\\x00v\\x11\\xfeA_\\xc2&j\\xb6\\xfa\\xa6\\xfe\\xd9?F\\xc9\\x05\\x99n\\x8a'"
b1 = b'E\\x00\\x05\\xad\\\\\\xd9\\x00\\x00v\\x11\\xfeA_\\xc2&j\\xb6\\xfa\\xa6\\xfe\\xd9?F\\xc9\\x05\\x99n\\x8a'
```

how to transfer str1 which is <class 'str'> to b1 which is <class 'bytes'>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`, to evaluate any expression in a string

```
>>> import ast
>>> str1 = "b'E\\x00\\x05\\xad\\\\\\xd9\\x00\\x00v\\x11\\xfeA_\\xc2&j\\xb6\\xfa\\xa6\\xfe\\xd9?F\\xc9\\x05\\x99n\\x8a'"
>>> ast.literal_eval(str1)
b'E\x00\x05\xad\\\xd9\x00\x00v\x11\xfeA_\xc2&j\xb6\xfa\xa6\xfe\xd9?F\xc9\x05\x99n\x8a'
>>>
```